# Ignore nth-child style in a nested list?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I'm creating a list of buttons which need to be styled differently depending on how many there are so that they can fit the container.  More buttons/options would mean I need smaller button sizes.

To do this, I'm using the following solution:

```
.modal-body-content li:first-child:nth-last-child(4), .modal-body-content li:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ li {
width: 48%;
height: 100px;
}
```

That would be applied whenever I have 4 buttons.  I've set the height to 100px as an example here.

The issue is that one of my buttons also calls for having a list inside.  The nested list needs to not get the styling from the nth-child stuff above.  I've tried to solve this using a child combinator selector but that doesn't seem to work.

**JSFiddle with child combinator selector (>):** http://jsfiddle.net/5j1yhj2x/1/

**JSFiddle with child combinator removed:** https://jsfiddle.net/a9mxqu5t/

In the first example, my list is maintained but the "height" property isn't working.  In the second example, the nested list is busted but the height property is working.

How can I structure these so that my nested list doesn't get the styling?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.modal-body-buttons > ul > li:first-child:nth-last-child(4), .modal-body-buttons > ul > li:first-child:nth-last-child(4) ~ li {
    width: 48%;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Can you show how that would work here?  Not sure where I'd need to put the :not without breaking the CSS which is finding the correct list length.

Comment: I've updated my answer. I misunderstood your question. I hope to get it right now :) What about selecting the exact child, so the style would apply only to you first level li.

Comment: That did it!  Thanks - didn't realize I needed to list each step of children when setting like that.  Glad I was at least sorta close :)